# Extract archive file using 7zip with space(s) in the folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

I want to extract all the `7z` files in the folder and subfolder using the batch below.

```
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.7z ') DO (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I"
)
```

But if the folder path with a space between, the batch is not working.

Example:

`X
 |-- a
     |-- 1.7z
 |-- b c
     |-- 2.7z`

The `2.7z` in the folder `b c` will not be extracted.

Can I know how to ignore the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.7z ') DO (
```

Turns off delimiters. By default, space is a delimiter, so `%%I` is set to (the string up to the first delimiter)